# Match two arrays with differents struct

Tags: json, go

I have the following

```
type Book struct {
    Name  string
    Pages int
}

type Library struct {
    Books []Book 
}
```

And from an api I get all the Books and transform them like this:

```
var books []Book
json.Unmarshal(response, &books)
```

But now I receive another list of `Books` from another api, but they come with different properties, which is why I add a `MetaData` property to differentiate them.

```
type Book struct {
    Name     string
    Page    int
    Metadata MetaData
}

type MetaData struct {
    Type     string `json:"type"`
    Price string `json:"price,omitempty"`
}
```

Then together both arrangements in one and return as json.

```
books = append(response.Books, response2.Books...)
```

And I add `omitempty` so that when they don't come, don't show them in the json, this is working fine.  However, every time I want to add a new field / property I have to modify my book api and the extra api that I mentioned above. I wanted to know if there is any possibility that a struct has multiple fields or accepts them rather and does not show them in case they do not apply.  You must say that I cannot modify the answers for the same format, and that they are all providers and it is out of my reach. The idea is to gather amabs answers and deliver only one to the front.

Comment: How would the API know which fields do not apply, can you explain with an example?

Comment: In this case, those that come from the new API comes with the PRICE field, which will not come for the old books.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be lazy about it: unmarshal them to an array of the generic type map[string]interface{} in stead of a Book-type.

```
var books []map[string]interface{}
err := json.Unmarshal(response, &books)
```

Ofcourse this makes it harder to access concrete book properties, but it's not impossible.